# How to initialize 2d array which is created by post method of form

Tags: php, html, arrays

I having a form which having one field of categories. User can select 0 or more then 1 categories(using checkboxes).
These categories are stored in cats variable or i am getting number of selected categories by

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="3" value="1"> 1

$num=count($_POST['cats']);
```

Problem is that when no category is selected that time no cats array is initialized so returns an error.
So question is that in case of no category selection value of $num becomes 0 and value of      `$_POST['cats'][0]="No category"`

Comment: I'd recommend just checking in php `isset($_POST['cats'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(empty($_POST['cats'])){
    $num=0;
    $_POST['cats'][0]="No category";
}
```

However, you should **avoid** modifying the $_POST Array on your own, copy the content prior to another array and modify this.

Comment: thanks @D. Schalla i just used empty($_POST['cats']) and helped me

Comment: @D. Schalla empty is not recommended in inspecting the existence of something as it will return true if the value is set to `false`

Comment: May I ask in which situation a form would set a value which is not an array if it is proper designed? This could be the case if and only if you modify the form or use unconsistent variable definitions. Please explain.

Comment: what will be the post representation of `<input type="text" name="textBox">` ?

Comment: $_POST['textBox]=""; but this implies that this would be in the form, what is not the case. Don't make it more complicated that it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that `$_POSTS` array have `cats` key with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cats']))
   //do things here with cats :)
```

An alternative way can be this :

```
if(array_key_exists('cats', $_POST))
   //do things here with cats :)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
if (!isset($_POST['cats'])) {
    $_POST['cats'] = array();
}
```

then `$_POST['cats']` will always be an array. But an empty array if the user didn't select anything

Comment: This does not provide the result he requested.

Comment: well your condition is wrong, it should be `if (!isset($_POST['cats']))`

Comment: this is also a good solution for my later use of arrays @WizKid thanks